# Passing Range to ABS function in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function, vba

I would like to perform a function which looks like this

```
Selection.FormulaArray = "=GEOMEAN(ABS((C646:E646)))"
```

Since my range keeps varying I would like to pass the range as a variable which looks like this

```
Range1 = Range("C646", Range("C646").Offset(0, 2)).Address(False, False)
Selection.FormulaArray = "=GEOMEAN(ABS(Range1))"
```

I get the error as #NAME?

But if I pass it this way

```
x = Range("C646").Address(False, False)    
Y = Range("C646").Offset(0, 2).Address(False, False)    
Selection.FormulaArray = "=GEOMEAN(ABS((x:y)))"
```

I get the error as #VALUE!

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the line `Selection.FormulaArray = "=GEOMEAN(ABS(Range1))"` in your code with the following:

```
Selection.FormulaArray = "=GEOMEAN(ABS(" & Range1 & "))"
```

I haven't tested this, but this seems right. (Note: your naming convention is confusing since `Range1` is really a string rather than a range.

Comment: Thanks I tried using as you had mentioned. It came out well for single range. When I tried copying it gives me same value for all ranges. My code looks like this Range1 = Range("C1467", Range("C1467").Offset(0, 2)).Address(False, False)
Range("M1467").Select
Selection.FormulaArray = "=GEOMEAN(ABS(" & Range1 & "))"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("M1467:M1667"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("M1467:M1667").Select. So I have to go to each cell having this formula and do CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER and then I get a right value. The formula array doesn't seem to work !!

Answer (score 0):

[ABS](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/abs-function-HA001228718.aspx) just returns the absolute value for a number not a range. Perhaps you want the [AVEDEV](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/avedev-HP005208993.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP005204211) function which returns the average of the absolute deviations of data points from their mean.

For GEOMEAN you either need to loop the range in code applying ABS to each value and building a new Range to pass to the function.

Or according to this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793724/excel-geomean-returns-value-sometimes) use an alternative formula:

```
EXP(AVERAGE(LN(A1:A171)))
```

Comment: I am trying to calculate average of log values (dB) Hence I have to use Geometric mean. Since GEOMEAN does not work for negative numbers I am trying to convert the numbers to ABSOLUTE value and then apply the GEOMEAN function. The catch is the formula Selection.FormulaArray = "=GEOMEAN(ABS((C646:E646)))" works perfectly for the range values mentioned here. But I have n number of ranges and I want to put this formula in a loop to calculate for the n number of ranges. Which is not happening !

Comment: @user216576 added more info relating to geomean

Comment: I would like to mention that I am a naive excel VBA user. So to overcome this issue I am trying out a work around. This converts each cell value to absolute and then calculates the GEOMEAN. Since I have negative values in some of the ranges I am applying the negative sign based on the initial cell contents. This method is quite lengthy hope some one could help me with a direct solution.

Comment: Spent more time on this this evening then I should trying to create a VB function. You should probably just create a new column apply ABS to all of the values and then take the GEOMEAN of the positive numbers. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.